# How do I withdraw money from BitPay?

Tags: withdrawal, bitpay

I have funds in BitPay that I received from several sales on my website. My split is **0% USD** cash and **100% Bitcoin**.

Is it possible to transfer this Bitcoin balance to another account within BitPay?

Alternatively, how can I withdraw bitcoins from my account? I cannot find a withdraw option in my dashboard section.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve: Do you want to move your Bitcoin balance to another account on Bitpay.com or do you want to withdraw them?

Comment: Hi murch,yes i want to move my Bitcoin balance to another account in bitpay.com.

Comment: Usually it is best to put the requested information directly into the question by edit, instead of only posting it into the comments. That way people will get the whole picture just by reading the question. Comments can then be pruned to save other readers the time. I updated your question with the information provided. - By the way, I don't think BitPay offers "wallet services" such as sending transactions, except for the preset withdrawal address.

Answer (score 4):

According to their support [site](https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/201890513-Getting-Paid) it should be on it's way without you doing a thing. I quote:

> If you choose to take settlement in bitcoin, BitPay will forward bitcoin payments to your bitcoin address on file. The minimum settlement is 0.01 BTC.

Maybe look on blockchain if there is an unconfirmed transaction to your address or [reset](https://multibit.org/help_resetBlockchain.html) Multibit if you are using that. Or you haven't hit the minimum settlement of 0.01 BTC.